# Assigning dynamic future value to document .doc('..') in FutureBuilder / StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner, so please forgive me a trivial question.  I faced a problem that seems to be quite simple to solve. However, I cannot move on until I understand this.

I have a `FutureBuilder` like this, which works fine:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('accounts')
          .doc(familyId)
          .collection('users')
          .get(),
      builder: (context, usersSnapshot) {
        if (usersSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        final userDocs = usersSnapshot.data.docs;
        return GridView.builder(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: userDocs.length,
          primary: false,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            //maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            childAspectRatio: 2,
          ),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          //reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => SingleUserFamily(
            userDocs[index].data()['userId'],
            userDocs[index].data()['username'],
            userDocs[index].data()['title'],
            userDocs[index].data()['userEmail'],
            userDocs[index].data()['imageUrl'],
            userDocs[index].data()['chosenOption'],
            //userDocs[index].data()['userId'] == user.uid,
            key: ValueKey(userDocs[index].id),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

As you can see, there is a dynamic string `familyId` in the Firestore stream. I can access and read this string (`familyId`) through the below Firestore query, which works:

```dart
  String familyId;
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('accounts')
    .doc('family')
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((document) {
      familyId = document['familyId'];
      // I get proper result of print (I see Id string in debug console)
      print (familyId);
    });
```

Unfortunately `FutureBuilder` does not see the `familyId` in it's 'future:'.

How can I use the value of `document['familyId']` from the above query inside the `FutureBuilder` stream?

Many thanks in advance for saving my life! :)

Answer (score 0):

These types of issues can be hard to diagnose without understanding the environment you are using. It is better to test locally as much as possible and review any error logs produced during the deployment process.

There are some excellent tools to test your Firebase code locally. If you [unit test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) your code incrementally and [interactively from a local shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell), you will identify any issues quickly.

You can also use the [Firebase Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to prototype, develop and test your code before moving it to production.

While testing is an integral part of the development workflow, writing logs for debugging and monitoring your code is just as important. You can create custom Google Cloud Logs easily to help identify the root
cause of your issues.

There are different ways to do this, but these examples below provide a basis to build on. You can read more about [Firebase logging here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's an object:", someObj);
```

```
const { warn } = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger");

// Attach structured data to the log as the last argument.
warn("This is a 'WARNING' severity message with some metadata.", {
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2'
});
```

**index.js**

```
exports.helloError = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log('I am a log entry!');
  response.send('Hello World...');
});
```